# How to achieve a smooth transition of the element going outside the borderline?

Tags: html, css, transition, mask

I have a container that contains a `div` inside it. By clicking on that div square, it begins moving and ends up being outside the container.

My problem is that this inner block is being trimmed out really harsh while going beyond the borderline. How could this transition be done more smoothly using CSS means? I want to get an effect when this square disappearing becomes gentle for the eyes.

Maybe I'm supposed to use some kind of an image mask for the main container or a fade effect for the square. I'm not exactly sure how to achieve that behaviour.

Thank you in advance!

[Codepan sandbox](https://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/rzpGOw)

```css
.borderline {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #0087ff;
}

.square:focus {
  transform: translateX(500px);
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class='borderline'>
  <div class='square' tabindex="1">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you could add an animation to your css with opacity like:

```
.square:focus {
  transform: translateX(500px);
  transition: all 2s;
  animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;

}
@keyframes example {
    0%   {opacity:1}
    50%   {opacity:1}
    100%   {opacity:0}

}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzppON

Comment: It flickers a bit at the end of the animation.

Comment: Well, twick the animation property whatever you see fit to make it as You wish. this is another example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdppor

Comment: Thank you. I like your approach, Alvaro.